# Writing code to only run when windows phone app is run for the first time

Tags: windows-phone

```
    private const string TERMS_KEY = "Terms";
        private static readonly IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string value;
            if (appSettings.TryGetValue(TERMS_KEY, out value) == false)
            {
                // means this is the first time they have started the application
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Terms.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
```

The code above doesn't work because I'm thinking that I have it in the wrong place in the program flow because I'm getting a null exception when it tries to navigate to the page but nothing in the code is showing up as null. I know this is probably an easy question but I searched online first and couldn't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the null exception before getting into the if loop or after?

Is the `TERMS_KEY` giving any sort of value when you run the application?

Check the navigation Uri too.

Comment: Yes terms_key is giving me the correct value and navigation uri is giving me a non null value as well. I just went ahead and did a different method for what I was trying to accomplish so I guess I will mark this as the answer to close the question. Thanks